# Displaying Images from disc in Image Component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an app that cycles through screenshots taken from my game. My current solution works for the first image, but after I cycle images it is not refreshing. My PropertyChanged event is configured and running fine. Only the image is not working.

My code for displaying is:

```
<Image DataContext="{StaticResource IMG}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
   <Image.Source>
      <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Image}"/>
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

and then my code behind retrieves the absolute Uri and is set via the bindings.

How might I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `UriSource` on the `BitmapImage` class will trigger the reload/re-render of the `Image`; `Image.Source` works, however:

```
void Main()
{
    var firstUri= new Uri("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e8b6a4ea2ee8aedc49e5e4299661543?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG");
    var secondUri= new Uri("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/23333db13ce939b8a70fb36dbfd8f934?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");

    var wnd = new Window();
    var pnl = new StackPanel();
    wnd.Content = pnl;

    var img = new Image()
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(firstUri),
        Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
    };
    wnd.Show();
    pnl.Children.Add(img);

    // Optional; just need something to change the img src
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        // The next line is roughly equivalent to invoking on
        // the Dispatcher (i.e., marshalling back to the UI thread)
        .ObserveOn(new DispatcherScheduler(wnd.Dispatcher))
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(secondUri);
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I posted what I got working as another answer. If I create a new BitmapImage and return that in my code behind it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code behind to return a BitmapImage instead of a Uri solves this issue.

this means that the XAML should be changed to:

```
<Image DataContext="{StaticResource IMG}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Image}" />
```